# How to get the 95th percentile of an average in Prometheus?

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql

So I'm aware of some percentile functions in PromQL like `histogram_quantile` which is used in a case like this:

```
// Over the past 5 minutes, what's the maximum http response time experienced by 95% of our users
histogram_quantile(0.95, rate(http_request_duration_bucket[5m])
```

And we can calculate the average this way:

```
// Over the past 5 mins, what the average http response time?
avg by (webId) (rate(http_request_duration_sum[5m])/rate(http_request_duration_count[5m])
```

Is it possible to combine these two function to get the query that means the following:
Over the past 5 mins, what's the maximum average HTTP response time experienced by 95% of our users? AKA 95 percentile of the AVERAGE?

I tried something like:

```
histogram_quantile(0.95, avg by (webId) (rate(http_request_duration_sum[5m])/rate(http_request_duration_count[5m]))
```

But it doesn't seem to work. Any suggestions or gaps in my understanding?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try the following query:

```
quantile(0.95, avg by (webId) (rate(http_request_duration_sum[5m])/rate(http_request_duration_count[5m])))
```

It uses [quantile()](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#quantile) aggregate function for calculating the given quantile over average response times calculated per each `webId`.

Comment: This seems to provide a single lined graph rather than split up into multiple lines representing the multiple webIds. Is that the intention?

Comment: Actually just added `quantile by (webId)` for that query and it worked! Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: If you need calculating the given quantile per each webId, then the following query must be used: `histogram_quantile(0.95, sum(rate(http_request_duration_bucket[5m])) by (webId,le))`

Answer (score 0):

I found the answers above didn't work for my situation, but [`quantile_over_time`](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#aggregation_over_time) allowed me to extract a percentile from a `sum`:

```
quantile_over_time(0.95,
  (sum by (component_name) (
     node_memory_MemTotal_bytes 
     - node_memory_MemFree_bytes 
     - node_memory_Cached_bytes)[2w:]
  )
)
```

Comment: What does that `:` in `[2w:]`?

Comment: I believe this is a [subquery](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#subquery) so both a range and resolution are required, denoted by `[range:resolution]`. If you leave the resolution blank it uses the global evaluation interval.